# How can I export plots within a list in R?

Tags: r

I have a list in R which includes plots as elements. Instead of viewing each element and saving it one by one, how can I export these plots and save them onto my desktop or into the R folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initiate a device (e.g., `pdf`), loop over your plot list, and then close the device.

```
pdf('path/to/pdf')
pdf.options(width = 9, height = 7)
for (i in 1:length(plot_list)){
  print(plot_list[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

This will create a pdf file that contains all the plots.